# Import data by text file to Access Database

Tags: ms-access, text-files

I am trying to import about 2000 `.txt` files into an Access Database. These text files are named after companies on the ASX, i.e. `ASX.txt`, `BHP.txt`... Within these files are csv's in the order of `Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume`. I want to be able to import all these such that it stores the data linked to the file name, e.g. when I import `ASX.txt`, it creates a unique ID for each date, `ASX20210101`, `BHP20210101` as an example, and then the corresponding data as a column.

Comment: OK - what have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is **NOT** a free code writing service, so please make some effort.

Comment: @Applecore I don't even know where to begin, Access only lets me import a single text file at a time, even then I still can't get the name of the file and make it correct.

Comment: Loop folder contents. Between each import run an UPDATE query that adds ID to newly created records.